# Getting error PKIX path building failed while using MailosaurClient with java

Tags: java

I am trying to read the email content with the help of Mailosaur. Below is my sample java code with Junit.

```
public class SampleEmailTest {

    @Test
    public void readEmail(){
        MailosaurClient client = new MailosaurClient("ABCDEFGHT");
        SearchCriteria criteria = new SearchCriteria();
        criteria.withSentTo("XXXXX.YYYYYY@MAILOSAUR.IO");
        try {
            List result = client.messages().search("", criteria).items();
            MessageSummary latestEmail = (MessageSummary) result.get(0);
            System.out.println("latestEmail" + latestEmail);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exceptio is " + e); }            
    }
}
```

After running this code, I am receiving below exception.

```
com.mailosaur.MailosaurException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Can anyone please help me on this front.

Comment: It's a problem with the SSL certificates. Is your antivirus intercepting SSL communications? They tend to do a MiTM attack to be able to scan your stuff over SSL.

Comment: I am not sure about this. However, I have installed the Mailosaur certificate in my jre. For that I have referred below stackoverflow issue.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ

However not getting any success.